# Embedding of countable abelian group into a finitely generated group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Prove/ Disprove/ or object

> Let, $G=\langle p,q\rangle$ be a group. Then there exists an abelian group $A$ with $\left| A\right| \leq\left|{\mathbb{N}}\right|$ and such that for every group homomorphism $\phi :A \to G$ we have that $\phi$ is not an injection.

**My thought:** I hold that $\mathbb{Q}$ is an $A$ that works for arbitrary $G$. Does $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ have any injections into any finitely generated group?

Comment: Is $\langle p,q\rangle$ meant to be a group presentation, or just to indicate it is some group generated by two elements?

Comment: It's just the group generated by two elements.

Comment: Your argument won't work: there is a theorem of Neumann and Neumann that every countable group can be embedded in a $2$-generator group.

Comment: Then how to prove or disprove?

Comment: I did a search and found that there is a universal countable abelian group, so you can embed that in a $2$-generator group and that will contain a copy of every countable abelian group.